# How to access network drive folder using credentials in R?

Tags: r, networking, server, drive

In my company we have Network Drives where we store flat files e.g. ".txt" files.
I have access to a specific folder of a network drive (e.g. "DNS_DRIVE\folder_name"), 
by using my Windows Credentials.
So I login to a Workstation (Workstation has network access to specific Network Drive) with my credentials (e.g. username:xxxx, password:yyyy) and in R Console I use the following command:

```
fread('//DNS_DRIVE/folder_name/flat_file.txt'),sep='|')
```

in order to read flat file and this works fine.

We managed to set an ML Server (R Server) (one-box configuration). 
When connected to ML Server (user:admin) I can't access Network Drive. 
Repeating the same code

```
fread('//DNS_DRIVE/folder_name/flat_file.txt'),sep='|')
```

returns the following error message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

I should mention that ML Server is set on a Server (i.e. "DNS_ML") that has network access to wanted Network Drive ("DNS_DRIVE\folder_name"). 
That means that if I use Remote Desktop and Login to "DNS_ML" using credentials username:xxxx, password:yyyy I can access "DNS_DRIVE\folder_name".

Is there a way to use in R specific credentials in order to have access to Network Drive?
Is there a configuration file or a library that could be used?

Comment: What about `file.exists('//DNS_DRIVE/folder_name/flat_file.txt')`? (Unrelated: there seems to be a typo with an extra parenthesis)